# Аналог lookupcombobox

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Есть DataGrid. При двойном щелчке на записи открывается форма для редактирования данной записи. Имя отображается в textbox'e. Необходимо сделать поле, которое дает возможность выбора из возможных вариантов(combobox).

```
TemplateBaseConneciton te = new TemplateBaseConneciton();
this.MainGrid.DataContext = te.USER;
```

Привязка к гриду:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Пользователь" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=NAME}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Роль" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=ROLE.NAME}" />
```

Создание формы редактирования

```
EditUserForm form = new EditUserForm();
form.DataContext = MainGrid.DataContext;
form.ShowDialog();
```

Привязка TexBox'a на форме редактирвоания:

```
<TextBox Margin="3" Text="{Binding Path=NAME}" />
```

Как привязать combobox, чтобы он предлагал возможные варианты для выбора Роли пользователя?
Возможно я неправильно пользуюсь Entity Framework'ом.

Comment: А как Вы пытались его привязать? Пока только для таблицы и текстового поля наблюдаю привязки...

Comment: В том то и дело, что я не понимаю как его привязать.

Comment: Ну, хорошо. Судя по Вашему контексту, который Вы задаёте форме редактирования, брать список ролей банально неоткуда. Надо передавать нечто больше, чем te.USER.

В зависимости от того, где эти Роли у Вас хранятся, такой контекст и задавать форме. А сам ComboBox привязать через ItemsSource к нужному свойству контекста.

Comment: Может я не правильно делаю. В модели EF в таблице USER есть ссылка на ROLE привязка 

    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Пользователь" Width="" Binding="{Binding Path=NAME}"/> 
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Роль" Width="" Binding="{Binding Path=ROLE.NAME}" />
работает. Поправльте меня, если так не следует делать.

Comment: тут ограничение на количество комментариев? К нижнему ответу не могу оставить - нет кнопки. Пытаюсь задать разные контексты. Комбобокс в итоге обводится красной рамочкой. Кажется истина где-то рядом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте переопределить [`CellTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

Update: То есть конечно [`CellEditingTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celleditingtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

Update: Для отдельного диалога редактирования, почему у вас

```
form.DataContext = MainGrid.DataContext;
```

?

Попробуйте

```
form.DataContext = dataGrid.SelectedItem;
```

---

Для правильных значений в комбобоксе делайте так:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues"
        ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}"
        x:Key="<ваш ключ тут>">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="<тип вашего enum'а>" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource <ваш ключ тут>}}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding <чё там надо>}"/>
```

Comment: мне не нужно редактировать в DataGrid'e. Именно на форме редактирвоания

Comment: А как насчёт смены DataContext'а?

Comment: Пусть так, но если я правильно понимаю в combobox не появятся все значения для Role

Comment: А, ну это другое дело. Смотрите следующий update.

Comment: Сделал через дизайнер

    <ComboBox Margin="3" DisplayMemberPath="NAME" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource rOLEViewSource}}" SelectedValue="Что тут написать?"/>

Не совсем понятно, может подскажете ресурс хороший по EntityFramework?

Comment: `SelectedValue={Binding <тут путь к вашему значению внутри DataContext>}`.

А чем по EF не устраивает MSDN?

Comment: А ничего, что два контекста? Один у editd'a, второй у combobox. Не до конца понимаю, как их связать...

Comment: @Serega Isupov, контекст можно задавать и в отдельности для каждого элемента, в конечном счёте Вы просто убавляете область видимости для того или иного элемента, так как ничто не мешает задать на верхнем уровне DataContext = this и потом везде строить длиннющие пути для привязки.

Answer (score 0):

Все. Добился я своего.

```
    <ComboBox Margin="3" 
                      DisplayMemberPath="NAME" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=rOLEViewSource}}"
                      SelectedValue= "{Binding Path=ROLE_ID}"
                      SelectedValuePath="R_ID" />
```

Здесь `SelectedValue` берется из контекста `Window`. `ROLE_ID` - поле в таблице `USER`, `R_ID - ID` роли в таблице `ROLE`.
`{StaticResource ResourceKey=rOLEViewSource}` - автоматический сгенерированный дизайнером ресурс.